# Primefaces 4.0RC1 menuBar with model attribute model throws Exception when rendering view

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra, glassfish-4

I have updated my primefaces version to 4.0RC1 since it supports JSF 2.2. (Over Glassfish 4)

i'm using a primefaces menubar to display my app menu, it used to work fine in primefaces 3.5 but it doesnt work anymore.

```
<p:menubar model="#{myBean.userMenu}" />
```

As you see in the code above, im using a model in order to display my menu programatically.

When trying to render the view, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:591)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:412)
    at org.primefaces.model.menu.BaseMenuModel.generateUniqueIds(BaseMenuModel.java:54)
    at org.primefaces.model.menu.BaseMenuModel.generateUniqueIds(BaseMenuModel.java:42)
    at org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel.generateUniqueIds(DefaultMenuModel.java:28)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:70)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.gbmemory.ebayresources.authorization.LoggedOutFilter.doFilter(LoggedOutFilter.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.gbmemory.ebayresources.authorization.RememberMeFilter.doFilter(RememberMeFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem for now subclassing org.primefaces.model.menu.BaseMenuModel like this:

```
public class MyDefaultMenuModel extends BaseMenuModel {

    private boolean generated = false;

    @Override
    public void generateUniqueIds() {
        if(!generated) {
            generateUniqueIds(getElements(), "_");
            generated = true;
        }
    }

    private void generateUniqueIds(List<MenuElement> elements, String seed) {
        if(elements == null || elements.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        int counter = 0;

        for(MenuElement element : elements) {
            String id = (seed == null) ? String.valueOf(counter++) : seed + "_" + counter++;
            element.setId(id);

            if(element instanceof MenuGroup) {                
                generateUniqueIds(((MenuGroup) element).getElements(), id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

id validation in mojarra doesnt allow ids starting with numbers

I've oppened and issue related to the problem [Issue 6187](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6187&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary#makechanges)

Comment: As an user of a beta version of a library, it's your responsibility to report this issue to the library maintainer. If you already did it, please include the link to the issue report in your answer.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for your suggestion, i have added a link to the issue i have reported as you requested